# Add query string to redirect URL in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I add s string to the end of a search result using .htaccess?

Original link: www.example.com/?s=search1 redirect to:
www.example.com/?s=search1&post_type=product

or 
www.example.com/?s=search2 redirect to:
www.example.com/?s=search2&post_type=product

"search1" and "search2" are variable.

I need this to change a Wordpress search result to a Woocommerce search result.

What a tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?s=$ http://www.example.com/?s=%1&post_type=product [L,R=301]
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` seems fine, except for one thing: the RewriteRule Pattern will be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and **before** the query string, so this should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !post_type=product
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/?s=%1&post_type=product [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your fast answer. After I apply your code I get some loop in redirection. Do you know please how to avoid this?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Working perfect.